# Pytest tmpdir writing to the end of a file

Tags: python-3.x, file, mocking, pytest

I am trying to test a Methode that writes in a file tow times with pytest. My Problem ist that the file I creat with tmpdir is acting like it is opend with  `open(„filename“, „w“)` and therefore overrides the first entry. But I need it to act like it is opend with `open(„filename“, „w+“)`. So the previous entrys are not overriden.

Code example:

```
import pytest

def read_tow_times(file):
    file.write("Monty Python's")
    file.write("flying circus")

@pytest.fixture
def mock_data_file(tmpdir):
    return tmpdir.mkdir("test_path").join("file_to_copy1.data")

def check_lines(file, text):
    for count,line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        if not line.strip() == text[count].strip():
            return False
    return True

def test_read_tow_times(mock_data_file):
    a = mock_data_file
    read_tow_times(a)
    text = ["Monty Python's", "flying circus"]
    assert check_lines(a, text) == True
```

Pytest error code:

```
========== test session starts =====================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.9, pytest-4.6.3, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0 -- 
/usr/bin/python3.4
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/a05922/rumprobieren/downsize 
code/fehler_tmpdir_schreibt_nicht_zweimal
collected 1 item

test_schreib_zweimal.py::test_read_tow_times FAILED                                                                                                           
[100%]

===================== FAILURES ===============================
____________________test_read_tow_times ______________________

mock_data_file = local('/tmp/pytest-of-a05922/pytest- 
74/test_read_tow_times0/test_path/file_to_copy1.data')

    def test_read_tow_times(mock_data_file):
        a = mock_data_file
        read_tow_times(a)
        text = ["Monty Python's", "flying circus"]
>       assert check_lines(a, text) == True
E       assert False == True
E         -False
E         +True

test_schreib_zweimal.py:21: AssertionError
======= 1 failed in 0.34 seconds =================
```

How do I get tmpdir to make me a file object that is not overwriten when I call .write() ?

Comment: `file.write("Monty Python's", mode="w+")`?

Comment: I tryed that. Sadly I still get the same error code.

Comment: My bad - wrong mode suggested. Replace `file.write("flying circus")` with `file.write("flying circus", mode="a")` to append to file. You will also need to write newlines to separate the lines, e.g. `file.write("flying circus\n")` etc.

Comment: This works great for the test example I wrote, but if I try it with a file I opened with:  ```with open(tmp_file, "w+") as target_file:``` I get:  ```    file.write("flying circus\n", mode="a")
TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments
``` I even tried: ```With Open(tmp_file) ```, but that didn’t work either.

Comment: These are two different objects. `tmpdir.join` gets you a `py.path.LocalPath` which offers the `write` method with the `mode` argument. The builtin `open` function returns a file object that is already opened with the mode you specified in `open`. Either use one or the other.

Comment: OK, but what do I use to mock a file object?